# reading json data in drop down in angular js

Tags: angularjs

while reading json data, i am not getting the value in drop down list,its showing 0,how to read json data for these drop down in angular

```js
function CountryStateCityCtnl($scope) {
$scope.types = [{
"category2" : {"type1" : { "size" : { "200x200x200" : [{"h1" : "200","l1" : "200","b1" : "200"}] },"coeff" : {"cement" : "0.02","sand" : "0.02","pop" : "0.02" } },"type2" : {"200x200x200" : {"h1" : "200","l1" : "200", "b1" : "200" } } } }];}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
     <head>
          <title>Cascading Dropdowns in AngularJs</title>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
          <script src="jdata.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
          <div ng-controller="CountryStateCityCtnl">
               categary:<select id="categary" ng-model="selectedcategory" ng-options="x for (x, y) in types" ng-change="GetSelectedCategary()"><option value=''>Select</option> </select>
               type:<select id="type"  ng-model="selectedtype" ng-options="x for (x,z) in selectedcategory" ng-change="GetSelectedType()"><option value=''>Select</option></select>
               size:<select id="size"  ng-model="selectedsize" ng-options="x for (x,z) in selectedtype.size" ng-change="GetSelectedSize()"><option value=''>Select</option> </select>
          </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"its showing 0"*  Have no idea what ***it*** is or what your specific problem is. Suggest you upgrade angular from extremely old version also

Comment: @charlietfl In first dropdown instead of 0 it must display categary2(from json data),and in 2nd drop down must display type1(from json data) and in 3rd dropdown must display 200x200x200(from json data). but the problem is its not taking json data in dropdown list.

Comment: @raj: the reason why you get 0 is because your first element in array is zero. In order to prove this you can simply copy your `$scope.types` value that is `[{...}]` and go to http://www.jsoneditoronline.org. Paste that value there and you will see how your array is built. You will find out that the first key is not `category2` but it is 0.

Answer (score 1):

According to your `ng-options` syntax, you expect the data source to be an object, but in your case it is an array.

Change `$scope.types` to be an object, instead of an array, by removing the square brackets [] and everything should work as you expect.

```
$scope.types = {
  "category2": {
    "type1": {
      "size": {
        "200x200x200": [{
          "h1": "200",
          "l1": "200",
          "b1": "200"
        }]
      },
      "coeff": {
        "cement": "0.02",
        "sand": "0.02",
        "pop": "0.02"
      }
    },
    "type2": {
      "200x200x200": {
        "h1": "200",
        "l1": "200",
        "b1": "200"
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: we can't remove [] because its json data.and the data format is like this only

Comment: Then your structure doesn't make sense for what you are trying to achieve. You will need to manipulate that data to be able to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Square Bracket, Because it's Taking array index as value for select dropdown.

```js
function CountryStateCityCtnl($scope) {
$scope.types = {
"category2" : {"type1" : { "size" : { "200x200x200" : [{"h1" : "200","l1" : "200","b1" : "200"}] },"coeff" : {"cement" : "0.02","sand" : "0.02","pop" : "0.02" } },"type2" : {"200x200x200" : {"h1" : "200","l1" : "200", "b1" : "200" } } } };}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
     <head>
          <title>Cascading Dropdowns in AngularJs</title>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
          <script src="jdata.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
          <div ng-controller="CountryStateCityCtnl">
 categary:<select id="categary" ng-model="selectedcategory" ng-options="x for (x, y) in types" ng-change="GetSelectedCategary()"><option value=''>Select</option> </select>

               type:<select id="type"  ng-model="selectedtype" ng-options="x for (x,z) in selectedcategory" ng-change="GetSelectedType()"><option value=''>Select</option></select>
               size:<select id="size"  ng-model="selectedsize" ng-options="x for (x,z) in selectedtype.size" ng-change="GetSelectedSize()"><option value=''>Select</option> </select>
          </div>
     </body>
</html>
```